# Output filename to VSCode replace string

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say I have a search I want to do across my entire project: `callToMyFunction()`

And I would like to replace it with:

```
callToMyFunction();
console.log("calling function from ${filename}");
```

Is there a way (or an extension) that could do the `${filename}` (or whatever) where the filename of the file where the replacement string is being applied gets written in?

If a search match was found in the file `index.js` the replacement would be:

```
callToMyFunction();
console.log("calling function from index.js");
```

[BONUS if there is a way to also get line number, but I'd be more than satisfied with just the filename ]

Comment: You probably can write some shell script for that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270048/369235

Comment: But I don't want a shell script (or better yet, a perl script).  I want it in VSCode  ;)

The tool has all of the information and capabilities built into it.  Surely someone has run into this problem before, and looked to solve it in the IDE?

Comment: It is pretty easy to do that - fileName and lineNumber one file at a time (let me know if you are interested in that) but I don't think you can do it across files, there just isn't an exposed api to do that easily.  An extension would have to get and examine the file contents of each possible file which could be done but performance would probably be poor.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that this would be any more difficult or expensive to do for VSCode than a standard Global Find regex search/replace where the replacement string contains a backreference?  It already has to look at the search result on a per-hit basis to get the replacement value, so i has already loaded the file, searched its text, matched to the regex, and calculated the replacement value?  Am I missing something?  (Note: I have not actually looked into VSC's code or architecture yet)